# How to set precondition for multiple s3 buckets in aws data pipeline?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

How can I set preconditions in data pipeline so it checks if s3 bucket exists and FAILS if it doesn't? I can set it easily for 1 bucket but I can't figure out how to update pipeline to check for multiple S3keys.

Here's what I have so far:

```
{
  "objects": [
...
    {
      "stage": "true",
      "name": "ShellCommandActivityObj",
      "id": "ShellCommandActivityObj",
      "scriptArgument": [
        "#{myEfsSource}",
        "#{myInterval}",
        "#{myRetainedBackups}",
        "#{myEfsID}"
      ],
      "runsOn": {
        "ref": "EC2ResourceObj"
      },
      "type": "ShellCommandActivity",
      "command": "#{myShellCmd}",
      "onSuccess": {
         "ref": "Notify_on_success"
      },
      "onFail": {
         "ref": "Notify_on_Failure"
      },
      "precondition": {
         "ref": "DestinationBucketStatus",
         "ref": "BucketWithScriptStatus"
      }
    }
    ....
}
```

I tried using list in precondition but then I get the following error:

```
Invalid type for parameter pipelineObjects[4].fields[3].refValue, value: [u'DestinationBucketStatus', u'BucketWithScriptStatus'], type: <type 'list'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>
```

Any advice appreciated,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In case someone can't figure it out.

Code is posted on AWS forum:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=266162